# Determining the rate of change of the x-intercept

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So my teacher gave me this question on a quiz.

Let the red line represent $ y = \frac{1}{2} x $, point P represents the intersection of the red and green line which moves along the red line at a rate of 2 units/sec. The green line intersects the y-axis at (0, 9) at ALL TIMES and point M represents the intersection of the x-axis and the green line. Determine the rate of change of point M given that the distance from the origin to point P is 10 units.

[image: graph]

I only know how to do derivates so if there's some way you can solve it without derivates, thanks, but I won't understand.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Is the point $P$ moving along the red line $y={1}{2}x$ or the green line? What is the green line? Is the point $M$ stationary?

Comment: @Brody Hopefully the additional information helps, to answer your questions: Point P moves along the red line, the green line is constantly moving, M is the POI of the green line and the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks! It's much clearer now. I'll get working on an answer, or an attempt at least. :)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but we may need one more piece of info. Is there a known position for either P or M at a given time? I don't want to just assume something like "$P$ is at the origin at time $t=0$".

Comment: Well you could figure out the position of point P given that it's 10 units away from the origin, then figure out the position of point MM if that helps.

Comment: I understand that, but we don't have a position coordinate w.r.t. time. Now that I think about it, we probably don't need one since the rates are related and the final answer is a rate itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let point $P$ be $(u,{1\over2}u)$. The equation of $PM$ is $y={9-{1\over2}u\over -u}x+9={u-18\over2u}x+9$.

Then $M$ is at the $x$-intercept of $PM$ so $M=(m,0)=({18u\over18-u},0)$

Now we know, The distance of P on the red line is ${\sqrt{5}\over2}u$ so $d({\sqrt{5}\over2}u)\over dt$$=2$ and ${du\over dt}={4\over\sqrt{5}}$.

Also, ${dm\over du}={18(18-u)+1(18u)\over (18-u)^2}={324\over (18-u)^2}$

At $P-origin=10$, ${\sqrt{5}\over2}u=10$ and $u=4\sqrt{5}$

Hence ${dm\over dt}={dm\over du}{du\over dt}={324\over (18-4\sqrt{5})^2}\cdot{4\over\sqrt{5}}=7.07$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(t)=\frac {t }{\sqrt5}(2,1) $$

the line connecting $P(t)$ and $(0,9)$ has slope
$$ m(t)=\frac{ \frac {t}{\sqrt 5}-9}{ 2\frac {t}{\sqrt 5}-0} =\frac 12 (1-\frac{9 \sqrt 5}{t})$$
the x-intercept is given by 
$$ x_{int}(t) = -\frac 9 {m (t)}  $$

can you take it from here ?